# OpenGL program validation fails with "Validation Failed: Current draw framebuffer is invalid." even though the application is working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I am working on a simple `OpenGL` iOS application in `Objective-C` and am validating the program in debug builds, like this:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
    if (![self.program validate:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
#endif
```

where `self.program` is just a thin helper class wrapping an `OpenGL` program. Here's the method implementation:

```
- (BOOL)validate:(NSError**)error
{
    GLint length, status;

    glValidateProgram(_program);
    glGetProgramiv(_program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
    if (length > 0) {
        GLchar *infoLog = (GLchar *)malloc(length);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_program, length, &length, infoLog);

        NSString *localizedDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:infoLog];
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Program" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: localizedDescription}];

        free(infoLog);
    }

    glGetProgramiv(_program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This is just a slight variation on Apple's sample code in the standard iOS `OpenGL` game template.

I am validation the program right after the program is linked and right before setting up the vertex buffer. I always get the following error, even though the drawing is working fine.

```
Validation Failed: Current draw framebuffer is invalid.
```

In fact, the strange thing is, if you validate the standard Apple template, which also works fine, you get the same error.

So, my question is, what is going on? I'm guessing that it's not actually an error, but a friendly warning, but I still would like to fix it and have my program validate successfully.

Comment: I haven't done OpenGL in a while, but I'm pretty sure that's an error. Show us your initialization code of the context, maybe that's where your error's coming from.

Comment: My code isn't particularly interesting and it's pretty long with many helper classes etc. You can get the same error by creating a new application with the OpenGL Game template and then calling the validation code after the program has been created.

Comment: If you haven't done much in your project yet, why not just start a new project, and keep on adding things from there and constantly checking if your code still works.

Comment: My code works fine, as does the template. I just want to know why the validation fails, even though the drawing etc. works.

Comment: The validation error doesn't appear in the update and drawing stages, so I'm assuming there are some linking of the framebuffer in the background. Maybe someone who knows about OpenGL on iOS more can answer that for you instead :)

Comment: It could be an iOS bug, because generally `GLKView` is responsible for doing initial frame buffer setup.